# How to change the name given with devise ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm currently working on my personal website.
By adding devise gems to my code, I'va made a mistake.

I've written :

```
rails generate devise MODEL
```

and I want :

```
rails generate devise User
```

I know I could just start over, but I want to know first if it is possible to change this and if it is, how could I do that ?

Many thanks,

Raphaël.

Comment: you could adapt the migration file and the model file by yourself. Or remove it and restart installation process.

Comment: Even if I've already migrate my DB ?

Comment: I posted an answer with the complete steps to remove an installed devise model. After that you can start again

Comment: why dont you use git to rollback to the initial state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Remove the table:**

```
rake db:rollback VERSION=versionNumberOfMigration
```

**Remove the configuration:**

```
rails destroy devise:install
```

**Remove your User model:**

```
rails destroy devise MODEL
```

Check the references to devise in your **routes.rb**, **controllers** and **views**.

Also check for the following code snippets in your project:

- `devise_for` (routes.rb)
- `before_action :authenticate_MODEL!` (controllers)
- `MODEL_signed_in?` (controllers, views) current_MODEL
- `MODEL_session` (controllers, views)

Comment: Sounds good indeed. But I still have it into my schema. How could I remove it ? By hand ?

Comment: If you did the rollback correctly it should be removed from the schema.

Comment: What was your rollback command ? The version number has to be correct

Comment: Right ! Thanks again !

Comment: Just running `rake db:rollback` without a version wiill rollback the latest migration. Passing a version is only really needed if you for some reason want to rollback multiple migrations at once.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

### rails destroy devise MODEL

Comment: Indeed, my models is deleted now. But I still have it into my schema. 
Should I destroyed it by hand ?

Comment: Like I posted in my answer your first step should be a rollback for the migration